# Placeholder Issue in jodit-react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jodit

I have been integrating Jodit-react to my react-typescript project but when I am adding config prop to it. It is giving an error as "Has no property common with type."

I dont know what is the issue with typescript.

Code:

```
const config={
    placeholder:"start typing...."
  }
```

inside return block:

```
<JoditEditor ref={editor} value={content} onChange={newContent=>setContent(newContent)} config={config}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't set the type of `config`.
So I think there are two way - first way is to set config type using `interface` and second way is to use `any` type.

```
const config: any ={
    placeholder:"start typing...."
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be define in Jodit Type  for config props?

Comment: I think we cannot define it in Jodit Type.